# Change zxing scanner rectangle dimensions

Tags: android, zxing

When i try and change the dimensions of the scanner rectangle of zxing qrcode reader, it changes it, but it stops scanning the qrcode.
I tried following to change the dimensions of the rectangle:

1. `onDraw()` function in `ViewFinderView.java`, i called `frame.set(0,0,300,300)`
2. `cameraManager.setManualFramingRect(300,300);`

both changed the dimensions of the rectangle but then it stopped scanning the code.
Please help me out here..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Same problem here... if you found a solution, please share with us!

Answer (score 9):

**If you're using ZXing as a library and can't modify the source code**

You can create a custom class that defines all of the camera preview behaviour, including removing the red line, making it square, adding custom logos, scan QR codes. All you have to do is create the following class in your project

```
public class CustomZXingScannerView extends View implements IViewFinder {
    private static final String TAG = "ViewFinderView";

    private Rect mFramingRect;

    private static final float PORTRAIT_WIDTH_RATIO = 6f/8;
    private static final float PORTRAIT_WIDTH_HEIGHT_RATIO = 0.75f;

    private static final float LANDSCAPE_HEIGHT_RATIO = 5f/8;
    private static final float LANDSCAPE_WIDTH_HEIGHT_RATIO = 1.4f;
    private static final int MIN_DIMENSION_DIFF = 50;

    private static final float SQUARE_DIMENSION_RATIO = 5f/8;

    private static final int[] SCANNER_ALPHA = {0, 64, 128, 192, 255, 192, 128, 64};
    private int scannerAlpha;
    private static final int POINT_SIZE = 10;
    private static final long ANIMATION_DELAY = 80l;

    private final int mDefaultLaserColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.viewfinder_laser);
    private final int mDefaultMaskColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.viewfinder_mask);
    private final int mDefaultBorderColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.viewfinder_border);
    private final int mDefaultBorderStrokeWidth = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.viewfinder_border_width);
    private final int mDefaultBorderLineLength = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.viewfinder_border_length);

    protected Paint mLaserPaint;
    protected Paint mFinderMaskPaint;
    protected Paint mBorderPaint;
    protected int mBorderLineLength;
    protected boolean mSquareViewFinder;

    public CustomZXingScannerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomZXingScannerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //set up laser paint
        mLaserPaint = new Paint();
        mLaserPaint.setColor(mDefaultLaserColor);
        mLaserPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        //finder mask paint
        mFinderMaskPaint = new Paint();
        mFinderMaskPaint.setColor(mDefaultMaskColor);

        //border paint
        mBorderPaint = new Paint();
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBorderColor);
        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mDefaultBorderStrokeWidth);

        mBorderLineLength = mDefaultBorderLineLength;
    }

    public void setLaserColor(int laserColor) {
        mLaserPaint.setColor(laserColor);
    }
    public void setMaskColor(int maskColor) {
        mFinderMaskPaint.setColor(maskColor);
    }
    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
        mBorderPaint.setColor(borderColor);
    }
    public void setBorderStrokeWidth(int borderStrokeWidth) {
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(borderStrokeWidth);
    }
    public void setBorderLineLength(int borderLineLength) {
        mBorderLineLength = borderLineLength;
    }

    // TODO: Need a better way to configure this. Revisit when working on 2.0
    public void setSquareViewFinder(boolean set) {
        mSquareViewFinder = set;
    }

    public void setupViewFinder() {
        updateFramingRect();
        invalidate();
    }

    public Rect getFramingRect() {
        return mFramingRect;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(getFramingRect() == null) {
            return;
        }

        drawViewFinderMask(canvas);
        drawViewFinderBorder(canvas);
        drawLaser(canvas);
    }

    public void drawViewFinderMask(Canvas canvas) {
        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();
        Rect framingRect = getFramingRect();

        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, framingRect.top, mFinderMaskPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, framingRect.top, framingRect.left, framingRect.bottom + 1, mFinderMaskPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(framingRect.right + 1, framingRect.top, width, framingRect.bottom + 1, mFinderMaskPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, framingRect.bottom + 1, width, height, mFinderMaskPaint);
    }

    public void drawViewFinderBorder(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect framingRect = getFramingRect();

        canvas.drawLine(framingRect.left - 1, framingRect.top - 1, framingRect.left - 1, framingRect.top - 1 + mBorderLineLength, mBorderPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(framingRect.left - 1, framingRect.top - 1, framingRect.left - 1 + mBorderLineLength, framingRect.top - 1, mBorderPaint);

        canvas.drawLine(framingRect.left - 1, framingRect.bottom + 1, framingRect.left - 1, framingRect.bottom + 1 - mBorderLineLength, mBorderPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(framingRect.left - 1, framingRect.bottom + 1, framingRect.left - 1 + mBorderLineLength, framingRect.bottom + 1, mBorderPaint);

        canvas.drawLine(framingRect.right + 1, framingRect.top - 1, framingRect.right + 1, framingRect.top - 1 + mBorderLineLength, mBorderPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(framingRect.right + 1, framingRect.top - 1, framingRect.right + 1 - mBorderLineLength, framingRect.top - 1, mBorderPaint);

        canvas.drawLine(framingRect.right + 1, framingRect.bottom + 1, framingRect.right + 1, framingRect.bottom + 1 - mBorderLineLength, mBorderPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(framingRect.right + 1, framingRect.bottom + 1, framingRect.right + 1 - mBorderLineLength, framingRect.bottom + 1, mBorderPaint);
    }

    public void drawLaser(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect framingRect = getFramingRect();

        // Draw a red "laser scanner" line through the middle to show decoding is active
        mLaserPaint.setAlpha(SCANNER_ALPHA[scannerAlpha]);
        scannerAlpha = (scannerAlpha + 1) % SCANNER_ALPHA.length;
        int middle = framingRect.height() / 2 + framingRect.top;
        canvas.drawRect(framingRect.left + 2, middle - 1, framingRect.right - 1, middle + 2, mLaserPaint);

        postInvalidateDelayed(ANIMATION_DELAY,
                framingRect.left - POINT_SIZE,
                framingRect.top - POINT_SIZE,
                framingRect.right + POINT_SIZE,
                framingRect.bottom + POINT_SIZE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld) {
        updateFramingRect();
    }

    public synchronized void updateFramingRect() {
        Point viewResolution = new Point(getWidth(), getHeight());
        int width;
        int height;
        int orientation = DisplayUtils.getScreenOrientation(getContext());

        if(mSquareViewFinder) {
            if(orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                height = (int) (getHeight() * SQUARE_DIMENSION_RATIO);
                width = height;
            } else {
                width = (int) (getWidth() * SQUARE_DIMENSION_RATIO);
                height = width;
            }
        } else {
            if(orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                height = (int) (getHeight() * LANDSCAPE_HEIGHT_RATIO);
                width = (int) (LANDSCAPE_WIDTH_HEIGHT_RATIO * height);
            } else {
                width = (int) (getWidth() * PORTRAIT_WIDTH_RATIO);
                height = (int) (PORTRAIT_WIDTH_HEIGHT_RATIO * width);
            }
        }

        if(width > getWidth()) {
            width = getWidth() - MIN_DIMENSION_DIFF;
        }

        if(height > getHeight()) {
            height = getHeight() - MIN_DIMENSION_DIFF;
        }

        int leftOffset = (viewResolution.x - width) / 2;
        int topOffset = (viewResolution.y - height) / 2;
        mFramingRect = new Rect(leftOffset, topOffset, leftOffset + width, topOffset + height);
    }
}
```

you can modify any attributes or methods as you desire.

After that, in the activity that creates the ZXing activity, modify the onCreate method to use the class that you just copied and pasted:

```
public class SimpleScannerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private static final String TAG = "INDIGO";
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    public static String SCANNER_GIVE_RESULT = "SCANNER_GIVE_RESULT";
    public static String SCANNER_RESULT = "SCANNER_RESULT";

    private boolean returnResult;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this) {

            @Override
            protected IViewFinder createViewFinderView(Context context) {
                return new CustomZXingScannerView(context);
            }

        };    // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new ArrayList<>();
        formats.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
        setContentView(mScannerView);                // Set the scanner view as the content view

        returnResult = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(SCANNER_GIVE_RESULT, false);
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to add round corner to camera

Comment: @Rissmon Suresh yes, you can basically draw anything, but you will have to figure out how using the canvas methods

Comment: @ibrabeicker Half screen when rotate on landscape mode why?

Comment: @ibrabeicker I want to create such app for barcode scanning, would you help me for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

The CameraManager class has two constants defined MIN_FRAME_WIDTH and MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT. You should modify them as desired and everything should work:

private static final int MIN_FRAME_WIDTH = 240;  // (your desired value here)
private static final int MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT = 240; // (your desired value here)

You could also modify the method getFramingRect() in that same class that creates the actual rectangle.

-- From another similar post [How to increase scanning area size in zxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398419/how-to-increase-scanning-area-size-in-zxing)

Answer (score -1):

Late, but a better way is to use the setScanningRectangle.

```
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
scanIntegrator.setScanningRectangle(width, height);
scanIntegrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
```