# How to increase scanning area size in zxing

Tags: android, android-camera, android-canvas, zxing, qr-code

Hii everyone currently iam working on scanning qr code from my app and i have used  zxing library and it's working good and  my problem is in my galaxy s4 mobile the scanning area is very small [image]

Please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use the source code or binary in your app? Will you be able to modify the source?

Comment: Iam Using Source Code i can modify it :)

Comment: I have already answered you what to modify. Please do that and let me know if any problems.

Comment: It worked and i have checked for xxhdpi devices and increased the size

Comment: How to decrease area of scan ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CameraManager` class has two constants defined `MIN_FRAME_WIDTH` and `MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT`. You should modify them as desired and everything should work:

```
private static final int MIN_FRAME_WIDTH = 240;  // (your desired value here)
private static final int MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT = 240; // (your desired value here)
```

Comment: Instead of MIN Width and MIN Height, you should probably change the MAX Width and MAX Height ;)

Comment: where is this class "CameraManager" ?  I installed this lib by add a line to app/build.gradle: `compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.3'`

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维 did you find any solution ?

Comment: I also didn't find the `CameraManager` class in `zxing`'s library

Comment: @SyedaZunairah I didn't find the solution because nobody care this bug in my project. I suggest you add this lib to your project as a module so that you can change and compile all the source code.

Comment: Where I find the CameraManager class ?

Comment: @AmulyaKhare where i get CameraManager class?

Answer (score 8):

I know it is too much late but help for others
just go to camera manager class and paste this code on replacement of given method
it works for all types of screens

```
    public Rect getFramingRect() {
    if (framingRect == null) {
    if (camera == null) {
    return null;
    }
    Point screenResolution = configManager.getScreenResolution();
    int width = screenResolution.x * 3 / 4;

    int height = screenResolution.y * 3 / 4;
    Log.v("Framing rect is : ", "width is "+width+"   and height is "+height);
    int leftOffset = (screenResolution.x - width) / 2;
    int topOffset = (screenResolution.y - height) / 2;
    framingRect = new Rect(leftOffset, topOffset, leftOffset + width, topOffset + height);
    Log.d(TAG, "Calculated framing rect: " + framingRect);
    }
    return framingRect;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public Rect getFramingRect() {
if (framingRect == null) {
  if (camera == null) {
    return null;
  }
  Point screenResolution = configManager.getScreenResolution();
        int screenx = screenResolution.x;
        int screeny = screenResolution.y;
        int width, height, left, top;
        if (screenx > screeny) {
            width = (int) (screenx * 12.5 / 100);
            height = (int) (screeny * 25 / 100);
            left = (int) screenx * 83 / 100;
            top = (int) screeny * 75 / 100;
        } else {
            left = (int) (screenx * 12.5 / 100);
            top = (int) (screeny * 25 / 100);
            width = (int) screenx * 83 / 100;
            height = (int) screeny * 75 / 100;
        }
  framingRect = new Rect(left,top, width, height);

  Log.d(TAG, "Calculated framing rect: " + framingRect);
}
return framingRect;
}
```

Replace the above code in CameraManager.java file
this worked for me try this out

Comment: hope this helps i know its too late

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this from another android app, use intent extras SCAN_WIDTH and SCAN_HEIGHT for this.

If you happen to be using phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner (3.0.0 or later), then passing the same intents like xxxxx.scan(onSuccessFunc,onFailFunc,{SCAN_HEIGHT:111,SCAN_WIDTH:222}) will produce the same result. 111 being the height, and 222 being the width.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ZxingScannerView, you can override `createViewFinderView()` and increase or decrease the framing rectangle size via `viewFinderView` like this :

```
scannerView = object : ZXingScannerView(requireContext()) {
    override fun createViewFinderView(context: Context?): IViewFinder {
         val viewfinderView = super.createViewFinderView(context)
         viewfinderView.setViewFinderOffset(-90) // increase size of framing rectangle
         return viewfinderView;
       }
    }
yourLayour.addView(scannerView)
scannerView.startCamera()
```