# How to increase the scanning area of zxing?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I want to increase the scanning area size of *ZXing*, I have already added the *ZXing* libraries to my app, but I find the scanning area is too small. I want to scan a large barcode, and I have encountered an error:

> Crop rectangle does not fit within image data.

The `getFramingRectInPreview()` method and `getFramingRect()` method does not return the same size `Rect`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase scanning area size in zxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398419/how-to-increase-scanning-area-size-in-zxing)

Comment: Anyone can solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
private static final int MIN_FRAME_WIDTH = 240;  // (your desired value here)
private static final int MIN_FRAME_HEIGHT = 240; // (your desired value here)
```

Comment: I have tried this, the scanning area size has actually increased, but i still need to put the barcode in a small area in the center of the scanning area, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To CameraPreView.java calculateFrames method and resize framingRect

`framingRect.set(left,top,right,bottom);`

I use this project to implement zxing scan : 
https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/releases