# Change Window Size for scanning QR Codes in zxing-Android-minimal

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I've integrated zxing-Android-minimal as described in https://github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal to my project where I want to scan only QR Codes.

Everything works perfect, but there is a little thing what I want to change.

When scanning I get a camera window where I see a smaller window that looks more then a barcode Scanner then QR Code Scanner ant the text below is for barcode.

I want to set the size of the inner window to a square and change the text.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

See here for changes to make for the window size (Hint: you just change the MAX_FRAME_WIDTH & HEIGHT):
[How to increase scanning area size in zxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398419/how-to-increase-scanning-area-size-in-zxing)

For the text, the 'msg_default_status' in the strings file contains the message.  Since you only do QR, you can just change the string.