# How to increase the size scaning area of barcode scanner using 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.7'

Tags: android, zxing

I'm usinng  compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.7'  github library. It can scan successfully barcode and Qr code. But the problem is the scanning area is small. Is there any way to increase the size of scanning area using this dependency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase scanning area size in zxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398419/how-to-increase-scanning-area-size-in-zxing)

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398419/how-to-increase-scanning-area-size-in-zxing

Comment: How you got to small ? this is default ?